# How to send large number of mails (more than sending rate limit) at a time in AWS SES

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an AWS SES service with a sending rate of 100 mails per second. Our application sends emails to all students within educational institutes. There's a need to distribute a substantial volume of emails, such as 1000 at a time, to inform all the students. However, we've encountered issues when attempting to send all the emails at a time, resulting in non-delivery. The number of mails to be sent may vary.

1. I'm seeking guidance on how to efficiently send a large number of emails within a limited timeframe without experiencing rejections or bounces, utilizing  other AWS services.
2. I would like to get a feedback in our application listing rejected mails, so how to find the bounced or rejected mails
3. is there any other way to achieve this using lambda/sqs

Comment: If you want to increase the number of emails SES sends out in a second, you need to raise the quota for your account.   
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/manage-sending-quotas-request-increase.html

Comment: thanks @JCompetence for the reply, but how much we can increase our sending rate. is it possible to raise quota upto 1000 or 2000 mails per second?

Comment: I suggest you start by asking them to raise it to the number you want, then see if they comply.   Nothing is free.  They will charge you based on the quota increase.

Comment: will aws charge extra for sending rate quota increase? it based on the mails what we send right? @JCompetence .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the total throughput quota is adequate to eventually send all your emails, and you just need a way to smooth the load curve, you should consider a system that queues emails and sends them at a fixed rate.

Here's an example of how you could implement a rate-limited email queue:

1. Add your emails to an SQS queue
2. Poll the queue at a fixed interval, pulling a batch of messages sized such that it will not exceed the service limits
3. Send the emails immediately using SES
4. Configure SES to [publish email delivery status](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-using-event-publishing.html) to a Kinesis stream
5. Consume the Kinesis stream from a Lambda trigger as messages arrive, and store bounces/rejections in your system

Polling the queue at a fixed interval can be tricky. The simplest solution may be an EventBridge schedule which triggers a Lambda every minute; that Lambda could (2) pull emails from the queue in compliance with your SES quota. However EventBridge schedules don't support an interval shorter than 1 minute.

If you need a shorter interval (eg for login codes that are expected to be delivered quickly), you could [add an intermediate such as a step function](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/a-serverless-solution-for-invoking-aws-lambda-at-a-sub-minute-frequency/) which would trigger the Lambda several times. In this case your EventBridge schedule could trigger the step function every minute, which would result in multiple Lambda triggers each minute.

If you calculate your timing and batch sizes correctly, this should result in a system that cannot exceed the SES rate limit.